# Is it optimized to design same temperature for several heat sink in a power supply?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, heatsink

I plan to use 5 heatsinks in a two-switch forward converter.

Should I to design same temperature for them or it is optimized to each heat-sink has a special temperature?

Comment: If you must use 5 heatsinks its unlikely that they will run at the same temp .Even if you miraclously get all the thermal calcs perfect the heatsinks are in different positions in the case.Your 5 heatsink approach has the advantage of telling you where the power is being wasted.This is good for R&D but consider reducing the number for production.

Comment: Good comment; R&D vs Production <==> separate vs reduced number

Answer (score 1):

I am making the assumption that by optimal you mean in terms of reliability and longevity. The amount of heat sinks you use does not necessarily matter. In fact, I would argue that the PCB layout should be the ultimate factor in how many heat sinks you use. Heat sinks are a preventative measure. It doesn't really make a difference if you separate each heat sink for each component or if you use a larger heat sink so long as your calculations and testing show that the temperatures stay well within the optimal component operation range. Just off of experience I would say that it would be better to use a larger heat sink for economy reasons provided that the components are near each other on the layout. What kind of heat sink you need and if you need to include other cooling features (such as a fan) will be determined by the calculations done beforehand. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ruFVmxf0zs) I have linked a video by Dave from EEVblog that should assist you greatly if you are having any difficulties with thermal design.